# "Сморозить": при чем тут мороз?

Tags: этимология

Сказать глупость — сморозить. Интересно, при чем тут мороз и какое отношение он имеет к глупости?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из В. В. Виноградова. "История слов", 2010: "Глагол **сморозить** в современной разговорно-фамильярной речи употребляется или непереходно, или в составе фразеологичского сочетания — сморозить чушь, вздор. Например, в водевиле Н. А. Некрасова «Петербургский ростовщик» (1844) в речи ростовщика Лоскуткова: «Разбойник! Мефистофель! Откуда она таких слов набралась! Дура сморозила, а ты и повторяешь — разбойник!». Ср. у Достоевского: «Он почувствовал, что сморозил нелепый вздор» (цит. по сл. Ушакова, 4, с. 307). Таким образом, сморозить и сморозить чушь, вздор — равнозначны. Слово сморозить было вовлечено в словарь литературного языка не раньше 30—40-х годов XIX в. Оно не было зарегистрировано ни одним толковым словарем XVIII в. и первой половины XIX в. Оно указывалось в «Опыте областного великорусского словаря» как народный провинциализм: «Сморозить гл. д. сов. Солгать, соврать. Костр. Кинеш. Кур. Твер. Каляз. Новотор.» (с. 208).

Никакими другими данными, которые связывали бы глагол сморозить с каким-нибудь определенным диалектом или жаргоном, мы пока не располагаем.

Этимологам естественно напрашивалось сопоставление этого слова с корнем морз-// мьрз-. Но непосредственно отсюда вывести его современное значение представлялось затруднительным. Преображенский осторожно и гипотетически заметил: «собств. дать, заставить, замерзнуть; откуда указанное переносное значение (`сказать глупость, солгать'. — В. В.), сказать трудно; м. б., это семинарское выражение, явившееся под влиянием гр. μωρός`глупый'; ср. ерунда, ерундить» (Преображенский., 2, с. 339; ср. междом. море, которое еще Памва Берында объяснял: `юроде, дурню'. Фасмер. Греко-слав. этюды., 3, с. 128—129). Эта робкая и ни на чем не основанная этимологическая гипотеза наивно-доверчивым филологом принимается за достоверную истину. Составитель статьи об этом слове в словаре Ушакова уже без всяких оговорок учит читателя: сморозить «из семинарск. арго от греч. μωρóς — глупый» (4, с. 307).

Как этимологические догадки бывают далеки от реальной и стории значений слова, легко увидеть, обратившись к слову сморозить. Это слово лишь каламбурно может быть сопоставлено с мороз. Например, в письме Вл. С. Соловьева к М. М. Стасюлевичу (от 20 января 1895 г.): «Спешу, впрочем, заметить, что сегодня на термометре — 26, а потому, быть может, упрекая Вас в гордости, я просто сморозил» (Стасюлевич и его совр., 5, с. 388).

Comment: Как интересно проходится Виноградов по догадкам этимологов!

Answer (score 4):

Я согласна Виноградовым о наивности догадок этимологов, связывающих значение слова с "морозить" И вот почему:

1.Слово появилось только в 19 веке, отчего не раньше,если "мороз" - древнее славянское?

2.мороз,замёрзший - замороженный - отмороженный - это скорее качества холодного, бесчувственного, равнодушного, черствого, бесчеловечного, до дрожи неприятного субъекта, родственны ему "мерзавец", "мерзко","мразь".

3.Десятки авторитетных источников утверждают, что ГЛУПОСТЬ по греч. МОРОС. Художественные произведения 19 века о семинаристах (Гиляровского, например) рассказывают о том, что они не понимали греческого,а он был обязателен, где-то встречала и фразу педагогов  гимназии "Вы морос несёте". Почему бы и не поверить, что нерадивые гимназисты или семинаристы, несущие околесицу, глупость,  переделали фразу в "глупость морозить", получился фразеологизм. Слово-то употребляется только со словом "глупость"и его синонимами.А отдельно - только в непереходной форме, больше в этом смысле ничего "морозить" нельзя.

4.Где-то по культуре речи видела разъяснение, что фразеологизм "сморозить глупость" тавтологичен, потому что "сморозить" - это и есть "сказать глупость".

Всё, по-моему, говорит за предположение Преображенского: "м. б., это семинарское выражение, явившееся под влиянием гр. μωρόςглупый'; ср. ерунда, ерундить» (Преображенский., 2, с. 339;"

Answer (score 1):

Жду "булыжников" в свой огород, но ... Не может ли быть в слове "сморозил" прямой связи с морозом. В том смысле, что при замерзании (отметаем летальный исход) наступает анабиоз, замедляются, притормаживаются все процессы в живых организмах, в т.ч. и мыслительные. "Сморозить" по значению близко к слову "стормозить".

Есть еще слова современные: "отмороженный (на всю голову)" (человек неадекватный) и "отморозок" (это уже полная деградация).

Answer (score 0):

Упомянутое, но не выведенное по-русски слово — термин *Маразм* (от др.-греч. μαρασμός — истощение, угасание) психическое, обусловленное атрофией коры головного мозга. Как известно, *маразматик* — в переносном смысле — тот, кто плохо понимает что-либо, ведёт себя глупо, допускает действия, лишённые логики и здравого смысла. Слегка созвучное этому термину слово *мороз* — никак не соответствует смыслу фразеологизма или глаголу *сморозить*, и должен бы был выглядеть на бумаге иначе, по крайней мере сохраняя безударную А. Но получилось то, что получилось.